# avoid javascript injection while maintaining HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-injection

```
 $("#id").append(dataHtml);
```

when injected with `<script>alert('test)</script>` an alert box appears on the screen showing test.I encoded the html but then it appeared as plain text.

I get the value of dataHtml from database.Because of some reasons I have to do this all on the client side using javascript/jquery.

How do i ignore such tags/injection while maintaing the html?

Comment: Am i understanding correctly that you want to exclude all script tags?

Comment: yes,I want to.anything malicious like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just use a simple regular expression to remove all script tags:

```
dataHtml = dataHtml.replace(/<script.*>[\s\S]*.*[\s\S]*<\/script>/g,"");
```

some explanation:

- `.*` : all characters except linebreaks (* times)
- `[\s\S]*` : linebreaks

to test if everything matches as expected you can use an online tool with an example of your dataHtml value (http://www.regexr.com/ for example).

Answer (score 0):

Append the script element with the type attribute set to something other than text/javascript, i.e. like this:

```
<script type="text/template">alert('test');</script>
```

This script tag will not be parsed or run as javascript.