# How to prevent <script>alert('data');</script> to execute in client?

Tags: javascript

how to prevent this situation where we are providing the header as a javascript and when it will display in frontend it will execute the script mentioned. 
so how to handle this type of situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [avoid javascript injection while maintaining HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054877/avoid-javascript-injection-while-maintaining-html)

Answer (score 0):

You should `HtmlEncode` the content before sending it to the client.